# Is there any React JS library to display the sytem language from React JS

Tags: reactjs

For example let us consider that user current language is english then while i display system language from React JS it should output 'en'.
I tried with os-locale,os,i18n and many more libraries but i didnt get any method related to system locale.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Library recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a great deal of sense. ReactJS is a client side library, it doesn't really involve Node.js other than as a build tool. Are you trying to get the language for the system building the application of for the system the user's browser is running on?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get user's OS language you can try to get it from environment:

```
const env = process.env,
language = env.LANG || env.LANGUAGE || env.LC_ALL || env.LC_MESSAGES;
```

Comment: Thanks,but when i used this ,it was displaying undefined.

Answer (score 0):

[os-locale](https://github.com/sindresorhus/os-locale) might be what you’re looking for.

But remember, this is for system locale. Of the server you’re running your Node API on.

If you want user’s language, you have to ask them. Which means in your app or website, you get the user’s locale and then pass it to your Node API.

Comment: Yes i was trying with my system language for internationalization.i used os-locale but diidnt get the results.

Comment: For internationalization, you should default to one language (English, for example) and then change depending on user’s language.

Answer (score 0):

if you want user's language you can either use [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) header in request (viable only if you're using server-side rendering in your app, i guess) or get it from [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) and send it to your backend